# Easily Export Visual Studio User Secrets Values to Production Environment Variables or Azure Key Vault

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using User Secrets for my Blazor ASP.NET Core 3.1 application and it works really well in my development environment.  However, I am anticipating the moment that I will have to export these values to my production environment and am having trouble finding any resources around this.

I did find this question/answer: [How to deploy ASP.NET Core UserSecrets to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668456/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-usersecrets-to-production)

However, it doesn't seem to provide an *easy* way of exporting data from development to production, which in my case would be either Azure App Service Environment Variables or Azure Key Vault.

Is the expectation that I will have to manually export each and every value one by one into the target destination?

That is what is implied in this otherwise well-written and valuable article regarding Azure Key Vault configuration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#secret-storage-in-the-production-environment-with-azure-key-vault

That seems like *a lot of work* especially with how easily User Secrets were to initialize, setup, and manage in Visual Studio.

It even has its own right-click menu!

[image]

In particular, I am interested in being able to *easily* export the Visual Studio User Secrets `secrets.json` file *with one command* to either Azure App Service Environmental Variables or Azure Key Vault.  I haven't decided on which one but one of these will be my final destination so it would be nice to know how to *easily* deploy to either of them.

Is this possible and, if so, how?

The thought does strike me that I could use a PowerShell script.  However, I am not finding anything of the sort and want to verify that something hasn't already been *reliably* created before venturing off to my own devices.

Comment: It seems that it's hard to export user secrets to keyvault with one command.